# Write list of comma separate strings to csv file in Python

Tags: python, list, csv

If I have a list of strings as follows:

```
data = ['a,x', 'b,y', 'c,z']
f = open('data.csv', 'wb')
w = csv.writer(f, delimiter = ',')
w.writerow(data)
f.close()
```

The problem is that they are saved in 3 cells on a single line like this: (" " is one Excel cell)

"a,x"    "b,y"    "c,z"

What I really want is the following:

"a" "x"

"b" "y"

"c" "z"

so that they are in separate cells and separate lines. Does anyone know how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create a list of lists(row) and write them all using [writerows](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows).  or write them all individually. The important part is that a row is a python list, not a string with comma seperated values.

```
data = ['a,x', 'b,y', 'c,z']
f = open('data.csv', 'wb')
w = csv.writer(f, delimiter = ',')
w.writerows([x.split(',') for x in data])
f.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

The below works for Strings.

```
   import csv
   data = ["Apparels,Clothings,Materials,Bazaar,Saree,Salwars"]
   f = open('data.csv', 'w')
   w = csv.writer(f, delimiter = ',')
   w.writerows([x.split(',') for x in data])
   f.close()
```